# Clojure REPL readline like support

Tags: clojure

Several REPLs (like ruby's `irb`) have some very useful features, such as using the arrow keys to "rewind" and "forward" the command history; but when I try to do the same with Clojure, it only prints garbage (I suspect it prints the keycode). How can I get this feature in the Clojure REPL?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `JLine` or `rlwrap`. Refer to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Getting_Started#Enhancing_the_Environment for assistance

Answer (score 16):

Download [jline from here](http://jline.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) and copy the jar to the directory from where the clojure.jar is loaded. The clj script should find and enable it.

On the other hand if you use [leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) to organize your projects, which I heartily recommned, then you do not have to do anything other than run `lein repl` and the REPL starts with the expected history behavior and all dependencies of your project on the classpath.

Comment: and if you are daring try cake as a leiningen competitor (uses same leiningen config files and a persistent jvm. its a lot less 'stable' than liningen

Comment: since version 1.3 leiningen has an interactive mode which keeps a single jvm and reduces startup time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you start your REPL. For example liebke's *cljr* has a nice REPL with readline support:

http://github.com/liebke/cljr