# How can i use /usr/bin/clj conveniently?

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clojure REPL readline like support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763926/clojure-repl-readline-like-support)

I am a clojure newbie. Today i installed it on my Arch box.

```
%pacman -Q|grep -i jdk 
openjdk6 6.b22_1.10.3-1

%pacman -Q|grep -i clojure
clojure 1.2.1-2
clojure-contrib 1.2.0-3
```

then i run `clj`:

```
%clj
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (+ 1 2)
3
```

All seems ok however i feel it is VERY difficult to use the clj interactive environment, where i cannot use
arrow key and so on.

What i really want to know is how i can config the clj interactive environment ?

Comment: See [Clojure REPL readline like support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763926/clojure-repl-readline-like-support)

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763926/clojure-repl-readline-like-support

Answer (score 1):

Don't use repl via the command line, install any one of the ide plugins, emacs vim eclipse etc. they all come with integrated repl that way you can directly send statements from your source files to the repl. Plus all of them supports arrow keys history etc. (emacs does)

Answer (score 0):

You already got two nice answers in comments, but this seems like a good chance to plug one of my projects, ClojureX:

https://github.com/citizen428/ClojureX

While developed for conveniently using Clojure on MacOS X, it also works well on Linux and even Windows with Cygwin. It will use `rlwrap` if it finds it installed and will fall back on the included `JLine` otherwise.